# How to prevent itemRenderers from being replaced with new instances in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, itemrenderer

The question sounds trivial, just set `virtualLayout` to false, but that's not what I'm after.

I've got the following situation. My Flex mobile app has predefined containers, usually half the width of the total application width. The user can maximize these components, so that they take up all the available width.

Naturally, for components that show data in a `List` or `DataGroup`, the renderers have to resize. That works out of the box, but I need them to show additional information when the components are maximized.
For that to work I created a very simple method to update the renderers;

```
private function updateRenderer():void {
            _itemRenderer.properties = {isFullScreen: _isFullScreen, headerProperties:_headerProperties, visibleColumns:_visibleColumns, optimalColWidth:_optimalColWidth, grid:this.name, fids:_fids};
            _list.itemRenderer = _itemRenderer;
}
```

The renderer properties, such as visibleColumns change accordingly and since the renderers will be invalidated automatically during a resize, they can redraw with the new properties.

That is all fine, but unfortunately, new renderers are created with this kind of procedure, instead of simply reusing the existing ones and let them redraw themselves.

Is there any way to alter this behavior, or does someone know a better way to accomplish a task like this?

Comment: This may lead into peformance issues and memory leaks. Why not use states ?

Comment: No memory leaks and performance wise I don't see the issue. Where do you see potential flaws with this method of updating the renderer? But you're right, states are probably the more efficient solution, the only issue I'm having with states is the way to change them. I need the renderer to be updated based on a resize of the host component, the data object remains exactly the same though, so it doesn't carry any information about which state the renderer should be in.

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu, on second thought, can't use states as the renderer properties are dynamically set by an external component. Renderer properties are for example labels and their sizes, the renderer than has to create labels according to the set properties, much like a table row with dynamic columns.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the code you show, it replaces the itemRenderer property; so "expected" that when this occurs, that all the existing renderers will be destroyed--as they were created with the 'old' renderer--and then replaced with an instance of "new" renderer.

You may consider changing the properties directly on the renderer:

```
   (_list.itemRenderer as ClassFactory).properties = {isFullScreen: _isFullScreen, headerProperties:_headerProperties, visibleColumns:_visibleColumns, optimalColWidth:_optimalColWidth, grid:this.name, fids:_fids};
```

And then forcing your dataProvider to refresh so that all the itemRenderers are redrawn, if needed:

```
(_list.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).refresh()
```

Comment: Tried exactly that (first that came into my mind as well), but unfortunately I get an error 1119 on that one: "ERROR: "1119: Access of possibly undefined property properties through a reference with static type mx.core:IFactory."

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either, getting a referenceError on that one: "Cannot create property " - one my renderer's properties - " on spark.components.LabelItemRender", which is odd because my custom renderer has been set before.

Comment: At this point, I'd request a runnable sample that can demonstrate the problem.

Comment: That should be possible to provide, would take me a few days to set up, though. End of this, or early next week sounds reasonable.

Comment: Alright, tested a little more and turns out that it doesn't give a compile time error any more (set up a different class). However, what this doesn't do is really update the properties in the existing renderer(s), in fact I only get null on my `properties`. Did you actually use this before and are you sure that this is supposed to work this way? If so I need to debug a little more and maybe do need to come back with some code.

Comment: Without reviewing framework code; I assume properties are sent in when the renderer is created; as such you won't get the new properties on existing renderers.  It sounds like you want to contradictory things; and you'll probably have to extend / modify code in order to send new properties into itemRenderers w/o causing a screen "flicker" as the renderers re-create themselves.

Comment: That's what I think as well. All the examples regarding this topic I could find so far point to the same result -> properties cannot be replaced on existing renderers. Bummer. That might very well be the right answer for this question then. But I already have a workaround in mind (you've gotta be quite creative sometimes if you want Flex mobile to work properly ;)).

Comment: @Al_Birdy I'd argue the functionality you're looking for is non-standard.  You're off-loading the creation of objects to a 3rd party class (using ClassFactory and itemRenderers) and want that same third party class to handle updates.  I wouldn't say you've found a case where Flex is working improperly.  Without extending the List class; you could possibly extend the ClassFactory to keep track of the components it creates and update properties when they change?  What is your work around?

Comment: Not saying that Flex is working improperly, you just have to bend it sometimes to make it work (read performs well for a large enterprise application) on tablets. It's just that the requirements I have are quite non-standard (for Flex that is), so I'm constantly hitting the limitations of the framework, but well, it is what it is. My workaround (till I have time to implement a proper solution) is to let the list re-create the renderers and then get some static objects the previous list renderers set before. Works for now even though it isn't nice.